# Constructing class which's property can only be set in constructor, but get anywhere?

Tags: c#, variables, properties, member

I'm trying to create a class which takes value `a` as a parameters in it's constructor.
It has a private member variable which stores this value. The value should not be changed afterwards.

Here's what I have, it works but I don't think it's the best solution out there:

```
internal class Foo
{
    private int a;
    public int A
    {
        get
        {
            return this.a;
        }
    }

    public Foo(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

So this way you can not access `a` from outside of the class, and `A`-property only has a get method. However, you can still change `a` from inside the class, and using a property which only returns one variable and nothing else feels stupid.

Am I doing this right, or is there a way to improve my code/more proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Additionally declare your private field [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) and you're there!

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public int Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return bar;
        }
    }
    private readonly int bar;
}
```

Comment: Ahh nice, hadn't known of `readonly`, I already tried using `const` but gave up since it can't be set in the constructor. Nice :)

Answer (score 5):

“In C# 6 and later, [you can initialize auto-implemented properties similarly to fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)”. Just like you can initialize a `readonly` field in a constructor, you can initialize a get-only auto-implemented property in a constructor. Thus, the following now compiles:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int A { get; }
    public Class1(int a)
    {
        A = a;
    }
}
```

…and the following yields an error:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int A { get; }
    public Class1(int a)
    {
        A = a;
    }
    public void Mutate()
    {
        // Class1.cs(11,9,11,10): error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Class1.A' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
        A++;
    }
}
```

I like it—you get the terseness of field initialization with the interface/OOP-friendliness of properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class Foo
{
    private readonly int _a;
    public int A 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _a;
        }
    }

    public Foo(int a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: This won't do what OP wants. You'll still be able to change `A` from inside the class as it's set to private. OP only wants to set it once from the constructor and so `readonly` is required.

Comment: Looks cool, but you can still change `A` from inside the class. Can you use `readonly` with properties?

Comment: Your Q is a bit ambiguous. As mentioned by @stakx, just implement 'readonly' if you need to assign the value once or use 'private set' if you do not want to expose set to outer class.

Comment: As keyboardP said it is not what OP wants.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen nope you can't.

Comment: I think this answer has been fixed. But now it’s indistinguishable from [the currently accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15720322/429091). Maybe author wants to delete it? Not sure what would be best…